# .bat file execution in python not giving the required results

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

This is the content of my bat file

Proselint is an exe file

```
proselint C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\proselint-0.5.3\proselint\proselint\something.md > ooo.txt
```

Running the bat file by double clicking it produces the following output

```
C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\proselint-0.5.3\proselint\proselint\something.md:2:1: misc.mondegreens 'a girl with kaleidoscope eyes' is the preferred form.
C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\proselint-0.5.3\proselint\proselint\something.md:1:38: misc.mondegreens 'laid him on the green' is the preferred form.
```

Which is the correct output in **ooo.txt**
But when i try to run the bat from a python script I get the following output

C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\proselint-0.5.3\proselint\proselint>proselint C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\proselint-0.5.3\proselint\proselint\something.md  1>ooo.txt

Which is nothing but the command which was to be executed
The python code used was:

```
import os
os.system("C:/Users/Rahul/Desktop/proselint-0.5.3/proselint/proselint/command.bat")
```

Note
: Using **SubProcess** also gives me the same output to the ooo.txt

```
from subprocess import call
call("C:/Users/Rahul/Desktop/proselint-0.5.3/proselint/proselint/command.bat")
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a different program than proselint? Using `echo` or another program in the batch file does not reproduce the observed behavior.

Comment: using dir command works perfectly. So only the windows inbuilt commands are working fine when run using a python script

Comment: Where did you get the windows build of proselint?

Comment: @Ashafix pip install proselint ?

Comment: But wouldn't it then be a Python module and not an exe file?

Answer (score 0):

Your .bat file must contain `@echo off` in the first line, like:

```
@echo off

command parameter > ooo.txt
```

If you do not specify `@echo` to `off` every line that is going to be executed will be printed to your console.

I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\proselint.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'proselint'

Comment: Could you please edit your answer with the actual code that is used to call proselint.exe because the problem does not seem to actually be the call.

Comment: My replication of your problem works flawlessly so I´m sorry, but I can't help you. I highly suspect that the error is not actually caused by the code snippet.